# How to add x-ms-dynamic-values in swagger definition through C# code for the azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger, openapi

I have need to [extend OpenAPI definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/openapi-extensions) of the azure function with x-ms-dynamic-values. I use that definition to create custom connector.

Currently I do that manually after the azure function is deployed. I take swagger definition and inject properties that I need.

```
   "/ShowUsername": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Show username",
        "operationId": "ShowUsername",
        "produces": [
          "text/plain"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "name",
            "description": "Name",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            **"x-ms-dynamic-values": {
                            "operationId": "GetUser",
                            "value-path": "username",
                            "value-title": "email",
                            "parameters": {
                                "name": {
                                    "parameter": "name"
                                }
                            }
                        }**
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "The OK response",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there any possibilities to do that direct in azure function code with annotations or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!